# Ошибки при компиляции

Tags: c#

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, компилятор отказывается выдавать ошибки, также почему-то не подсвечиваются классы. И не может найти путь к файлу, хотя если указать ему через cd, и пробилдить работает только если ошибок нет.[image: Ошибка]

После пересбора вылезло это[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам ведь пишет прямым текстом "установите SDK!".

Comment: @EvgeniyZ он установлен

Comment: Как вы поняли, что он установлен? Что dotnet version говорит?